# UNIX Shell Script Backup Directory on Specific day

Tags: shell, scripting, tar, zip

Basically this is the question im trying to answer

2)  Write a shell script (fridaybackup.sh) which will, if run on Friday, backup all files in user2 home directory. The script will create a backup (tar) file named user2backup.tar and zip file named user2backup.zip

This is what I have so far

```
    #!/bin/sh
    echo
    echo "Do you want to create a full backup (Y=Yes, N=No) : \c"
    read INPUT

    day=$(date +%A)
    time=$(date +%m-%d-%y)
    filename=user2backup${time}.tar.gz
    srcdir='/export/home/student/user2'
    desdir='/export/home/student/backupfolder'

   case $INPUT in
   N) echo "Bye." ;;
   Y)
   if [ "$day" = "Monday" ]
   then 
   tar -cpzf $desdir/$filename $srcdir

    else
    echo "A full backup is done on Fridays only!!!"

     fi ;;
    *) echo "Error" ;;
  esac
```

But I get this result

```
    student@solaris:~/user2$ sh fridaybackup.sh

    Do you want to create a full backup (Y=Yes, N=No) : Y
    tar: /export/home/student/backupfolder/user2backup10-02-17.tar.gz: No 
     such file or directory
    student@solaris:~/user2$ gedit fridaybackup.sh
```

Any help would be great and thanks in advance

Comment: If your variables are set the result of the execution of a given UNIX/Linux command then it should be within $() and so for example day=$(date +%A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there seems to be a copy/paste problem,

variable must be set using

```
day=$(date +%A)
```

I believe you use backtick, that dissapear under formating, as "Monday" error shows.

there is a syntax error near `if`

> error Monday: not found

prove that setting was correct, as in line 14 bash encounter :

```
( Monday = friday )
```

this forked a sub shell, running `Monday` as program name and `= Friday` as argument. This is not what you intend.

In shell test are done using

```
if [ "$day" = "Friday" ]
```

or

```
if test "$day" = "Friday"
```

thus correct shell look like :

```
#!/bin/sh
 echo
 echo "Do you want to create a full backup (Y=Yes, N=No) : \c"
 read INPUT

 day=$(date +%A)
 time=$(date +%m-%d-%y)
 filename=user2backup$time.tar.gz
 srcdir='/export/home/student/user2'
 desdir='/export/home/student/backupfolder'

 case $INPUT in
 N) echo "Bye." ;;
 Y)
 if [ "$day" = "Friday" ]
 then 
 tar -cpzf $desdir/$filename $srcdir

 else
 echo "A full backup is done on Fridays only!!!"

 fi ;;
 *) echo "Error" ;;
 esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `read -p "Do you want to create a full backup (Y=Yes, N=No) : " INPUT` instead of your:

```
echo "Do you want to create a full backup (Y=Yes, N=No) : \c"
read INPUT
```

EDIT: Also as @Raman in comment explained, you made mistake declaring your variables.

This would be the best and most safe way to declare your `filename` variable:

```
filename="user2backup${time}.tar.gz"
```

Answer (score 0):

The description does not require asking the user. It could do it automatically:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 if [ $(date +%A) = Friday ]; then
    TARFILE=/export/home/student/backupfolder/user2backup$(date +%m-%d-%y).tar
    tar -cpf $TARFILE /export/home/student/user2
    zip $TARFILE.zip $TARFILE
 fi
```